# Bug in Bing Map API SDK Direction Module

Tags: bing-maps

In application I have Bing Maps API (Release Branch). Today suddenly I saw something wrong with direction module. I have set below mentioned direction modules option which were working earlier but not now. In below code I am trying to hide route and waypoints. It works for waypoints but not for route.

So I tried bing map SDK online example where I try to set routeDraggable : false but in the SDK example is not working.

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', () => {
  that.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(that.map);
  // Set Route Mode to driving

  that.directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
    routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving,
    routeDraggable: false
  });

  that.directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
    drivingPolylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: 'green',
      strokeThickness: 3,
      visible: false
    },
    waypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    viapointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    autoUpdateMapView: false
  });

  const waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(startLoc.latitude, startLoc.longitude), icon: ''
  });
  const waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(endLoc.latitude, endLoc.longitude)
  });
  this.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
  this.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);

  // Add event handler to directions manager.
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function (e) {
    // const that = this;
    console.log(e);
    var routeIndex = e.route[0].routeLegs[0].originalRouteIndex;
    var nextIndex = routeIndex;
    if (e.route[0].routePath.length > routeIndex) {
      nextIndex = routeIndex + 1;
    }
    var nextLocation = e.route[0].routePath[nextIndex];
    var pin = that.map.entities.get(index);
    // var bearing = that.calculateBearing(startLoc,nextLocation);
    that.MovePinOnDirection(that, e.route[0].routePath, pin, truckUrl, truckIdRanId);
  });

  this.directionsManager.calculateDirections();
});
```

https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/directionsgetrequestoptions

[image]

@rbrundritt Can you help me in this issue ?

Comment: I haven't worked with Bing Maps for close to a year now, so likely won't be much help. Some people on the Bing Maps team are monitoring the forums, so one of them should be able to assist.

Comment: No problem Ricky. I checked on the forum and came to know many other people face the same issue which I have mentioned. Let's wait & watch until any official announcement.